# Detached webview with service?

Tags: android, cordova

When my app exits (back button, exitApp call, task killer, etc.) it leaves a detached webview that I can see in Chrome's inspector; the webview is still running even though my app has closed. However, if I don't start a foreground service, the webview closes as expected.

I'd like to fix this - both to be kind to the user's memory, and to prevent zombie webviews from doing work and creating havoc.

It sounds to me like there is some reference between the webview and service (webview has some service ref or vice versa), but I can't find the connection - I start the service up, I don't hold a reference to it, and it communicates with my CordovaPlugin class by broadcasting intents.

Is this a general problem, that if an app runs a service then its webview won't die? If it isn't, how can I find what's keeping the webview alive?

EDIT - a comment asked for code, so I created a sample project... the startForeground call causes the zombie webviews (w/o this call, webviews close instead of staying open as 'detached').

```
package com.example.plugin;

import org.apache.cordova.*;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Service;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class Hello extends CordovaPlugin {

    private final static String LOG_TAG = "****** SERVICE STARTER *******";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("startService")) {
            startService();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void startService() {
        Context context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        Intent service = new Intent(context, EmptyService.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }

    public final static class EmptyService extends Service {
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            // zombies created if this startForeground call is included
            startForeground(1, getNotification());
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        private Notification getNotification() {
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
            builder
                .setContentTitle("Service")
                .setContentText("Running in fg, baby");
            Notification notification = builder.build();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
            return notification; 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't speak for Cordova specifically, but if your process is running, and the process had a `WebView` in it, it may be a while before that `WebView` gets garbage-collected. And, if something static has a reference to it (direct or indirect), the `WebView` cannot be garbage-collected.

Comment: Posting code would be helpful.

Comment: @CommonsWare Cordova does try to destroy the webviews, and I don't see any reference to my webview in my EmptyService above...

Comment: I have the same problem without Cordova. The detached WebViews are annoying, because they are causing conflicts in my XMLHttpRequests: only the fastest WebView catches the server notification, marks it read, so the currently visible view don't get notified. I need to kill these WebViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently a bug in Cordova - Cordova 5.0.0 doesn't have this behavior, so upgrading from 3.6 to 5.0 fixes it for me.